# Brightness of LED panel

Tags: lumen, led-lighting

If choosing a xenon flash, GN is a common reference. Come to led panel, there is lm/m and lux.

This is a spec. of led panel:

LM: 520/m

LUX: 1m: 650, 2m:170, 3m:80

Whats EV equivalent of above figure? If ISO 100, what's f no. and shutter speed of it?

Thank you.